# Get grid reference with lookupReference or button.up() - best way

Tags: extjs, reference, extjs5

In an app with a grid and a toolbar with a button, which is the most correct solution (and improved performance) for get the grid reference from the button event:

```
button.up('grid')
```

or

```
this.lookupReference('gridReference');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lookup is the better way, as of ExtJS 5. It will be slightly more performant, but mostly the reason it's better is that it decouples the logic of what you want to do (find the grid) from your knowledge of the component's layout.

(Both references and component queries get cached; the reference's cache is in the component that declares the reference, while the component query cache is global, but limited in size. The reference cache is updated when the referred object is created, and will be valid until the object dies. The component query cache can be stale, and the cached reference can be kicked out - that's why the reference is slightly more performant.)